# amCharts 4: How to handle real gaps?

Tags: amcharts

I have date based Data with real gaps in it, not only the value is missing, also the date is missing. In amCharts 3, graph.connect = false, the Date based chart produced gaps.
In amCharts 4 series.connect = false only works if at least one data point follows with only the date, but without the value.
Is it some how possible to produce gaps when the whole data point is missing?

The demos with gaps always have at least on data point for the gap.

Comment: An issue has been opened: https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/636

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue with David Liang's answer, you have to put connect=false and use autoGapCount. But be careful as it won't work with XYCharts!

Taken from amcharts:

The feature (available since version 4.2.4) responsible for that is called autoGapCount, and it works like this: if the distance between two adjacent data points is bigger than baseInterval * autoGapCount and connect = false the line breaks.

The default for this setting is 1.1 which means that if the distance is at least 10% greater than the granularity of data, we consider it a gap.

Looking at the sample data above, we have daily granularity: distance between each data point is one day (24 hours). Now, since April 22nd is missing the distance between 21st and 23rd becomes two days (48 hours) which satisfies "gap" criteria (24 hours * 1.1 = 26.4 hours). Boom - a gap.

This allows fine-grained control of what to consider a gap in the data. Say we want a line to break only if there's a distance of three days between data points: we set autoGapCount = 3. Now, if there's distance of one or two days between two data points, they'll be connected, even if connect = false